# How to separate an array by a property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I have an array of products that have 5 properties, one of those being "category". What i want to achieve is to get a new array that separates these products by category BUT with the category in a "title" property, so the final array has the shape of

```
[{
title: "category1",
data: [{product1,product2,...}]
},{
title: "category2",
data: [{product3,product4,...}]}
]
```

I found a similar question but that doesnt give me the "title" prop, instead it gives me:

```
[{
cateogry1: [{product1,product2,...}],
category2: [{product3,product4,...}],
}]
```

And this doesnt work because im trying to use this array in a SectionList in ReactNative which needs the data to have the other specific shape. If anyones know a way in which I can separate the array like this or use the original array in a SectionList that would be great.

Comment: please add the raw data. what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method of the Array to "map" your items one after the other

```js
// You can have as many extra attributes as you want inside here. I only put "index"
const products = [{
    category: 'category1',
    index: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'category2',
    index: '2'
  },
  {
    category: 'category2',
    index: '3'
  },
  {
    category: 'category1',
    index: '4'
  },
  {
    category: 'category1',
    index: '5'
  },
  {
    category: 'category2',
    index: '6'
  },
]


// Use a reduce on the existing array. It iterate on the array and provide 
// an accumulator (here called acc) initialized at the last row as an empty array
const transformedProducts = products.reduce((acc, product) => {
  // Look for an existing object. Search in the accumulator a title equal to the current iterated product category
  const index = acc.findIndex(group => group.title === product.category)
    
  if(index < 0) {
      // If no existing object is found you create one and put the iterated product in it
      acc.push({ title: product.category, data: [product] })
  } else {
      // If you find it you use it to add the new product to the list
      acc[index].data = [...acc[index].data, product]
  }
    
  return acc
}, []);
```

Comment: This is totally acceptable in most cases (I upvoted), but note that it is extremely inefficient to look for a key in an array of objects, since you have to iterate through the whole array instead of a simple O(1) lookup on an object. Memoizing the indexes of added categories will make the operation more than 10x faster in a medium-sized dataset. May not be much of an issue when there aren't too many products, but good to keep in mind for when you're building the next Amazon  [Here's a benchmark](https://jsbench.me/zalfhhcgn6/1)

Comment: @rhelminen Totally agree! Thanks for improving this answer!